# How can I prevent items in one list from being dropped into another nest ul jquery sortable?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have nested lists, each one with a unique ID. I am wondering how I can prevent the parent-parent list items from dropping into an inner section `<div>` inside an `<li> <div>` which already contains a `<ul> <li>` list of its own. In addition, the placeholder appears there too. I am wondering if there is a way to force the items that belong to the first list to stay there even if they move above another nested list with an item in the main global list.

Thanks in advance.

**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             $('ul#main-sections').sortable({
                 connectWith: 'ul#main-sections', 
                 items: 'li:not(:last-child)',
                 placeholder: 'placeholder',
                 forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                 start: function (e, ui) {
                     var elementHeight = ui.item.height();
                     ui.placeholder.height(elementHeight);
                 }
             });
         });
```

**Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/wt4N8/1/** <-- drag summary over books section and you'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clarify your jQuery selector like that:

```
items: '>li:not(:last-child)',
```

It will select only first level child elements

http://jsfiddle.net/wt4N8/2/

Is it what you are looking for?

P.S. Here is how you can arrange Books and Summary sections: http://jsfiddle.net/wt4N8/3/

Answer (score 0):

make all the nested and parent lists sortable  then set

```
items: '>li'
```

this will solve the issue. it worked for me.